# What happens in Java overloading a method that has a param a subtype of the param taken from the other method?

Tags: java, parent-child, overloading, parent

The title can be a bit confusing, let me explain with an example.
Suppose that I have two classes:

```
class Parent {} 

class Child extends Parent {}
```

Then somewhere else  I define a method that has a single parameter of type Parent, like this:

```
public void doSomething(Parent parameter) {...}
```

Because of polymorphism I can pass to the method above also an object of type Child because it extends Parent.

Now let's do an overload

```
public void doSomething(Parent parameter) {...}

public void doSomething(Child parameter) {...}
```

and then in some other part of the code call doSomething passing a parameter of type Child

```
Child myElement = new Child();
doSomething(myElement);
```

In this case both the overloaded method are valid because the element of type Child can be passed to both.
Which one will be called?

I wrote a test and it seems that the second one (the one that takes the parameter of type Child in input) is executed, and it make also sense to me, but I would like to know if it is a well defined behavior or can vary basing on for example the jvm implementation or the order in which the two methods are declared or just randomly etc.

Comment: Everything in Java is defined (and if it isn't, that is probably a bug). If you want the nitty-gritty details look at [JLS 8.4.9 Overloading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9) and [JLS 15.12 Method Invocation Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, the method with the most specific parameters will be called. In your example, the method that takes a `Child` is more specific than the method that takes a `Parent` so it's the former that is called.

The [actual rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12) are somewhat complex but are well defined and part of the language specification. A valid compiler or JVM must follow those rules.

Comment: OK but pay attention to this: in case of `Parent myElement = new Child()`, the call `doSomething(myElement)` will invoke the first one.

Comment: "the actual rules are somewhat complex" but most definitely not dependent upon the implementation or the declaration order.